# Photon "Failed to 'network-remove' GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Photon.Realtime;
using Photon.Pun;

public class Player1 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int maxHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth = 100;
    PhotonView myPhotonView;
    public HealthBar healthBar;
    public GameObject Controller;

    void Start()
    {
        
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }


    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        if (!myPhotonView.IsMine)
        {
            currentHealth -= damage;
            Debug.Log(currentHealth);
            
            if (currentHealth <= 0)
            {
                Kill();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Kill()
    {
        if (!myPhotonView.IsMine)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        myPhotonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();

        if (!myPhotonView.IsMine)
        {

            {
                if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
                {
                    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
                    TakeDamage(20);
                    Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
                }

                if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet2")
                {
                    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
                    TakeDamage(40);
                    Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
                }

                if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet3")
                {
                    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
                    TakeDamage(50);
                    Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
                }

                if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet4")
                {
                    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
                    TakeDamage(100);
                    Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Whenever I try to remove a player that has died I get this error.**

Failed to 'network-remove' GameObject. Client is neither owner nor masterClient taking over for owner who left: View (0)2001 on Player(Clone)

I've tried everything to make this work it just won't I know it has something to do with photon view but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not owner of object or master client, so you can not destroy that object.

You can send RPC to master client to ask master destroy it.